In WXwidgets, how can I bind an event in one class to a function from a different class
Using wxwidgets in C++, I am trying to bind an event in one class to functions in different classes. Here is a minimal reproducable example:
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/notebook.h>
#include <wx/panel.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)


class Notebook : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Notebook(const wxString& title);
};


class MyPanelA : public wxPanel
{
public:
    MyPanelA(wxNotebook* parent);
    void FuncA(wxCommandEvent& event);
};

class MyPanelB : public wxPanel
{
public:
    MyPanelB(wxNotebook* parent);
    void FuncB(wxCommandEvent& event);
};


bool MyApp::OnInit()
{

    Notebook* notebook = new Notebook(wxT("Notebook"));
    notebook->Show(true);

    return true;
}

Notebook::Notebook(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400, 350))
{

    wxNotebook* nb = new wxNotebook(this, -1, wxPoint(-1, -1),
        wxSize(-1, -1), wxNB_BOTTOM);

    MyPanelA* panel1 = new MyPanelA(nb);
    MyPanelB* panel2 = new MyPanelB(nb);

    nb->AddPage(panel1, wxT("Sheet1"));
    nb->AddPage(panel2, wxT("Sheet2"));

    CreateStatusBar();
    Center();
}


MyPanelA::MyPanelA(wxNotebook* parent)
    : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    wxButton* Button1 = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Button A"));
    Button1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelA::FuncA, this, wxID_ANY);   
    //Button1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelB::FuncB, this, wxID_ANY);
}

MyPanelB::MyPanelB(wxNotebook* parent)
    : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    wxButton* Button2 = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Button B"));
    Button2->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelB::FuncB, this, wxID_ANY);
    //Button2->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelA::FuncA, this, wxID_ANY);
}

void MyPanelA::FuncA(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is Func A");
}

void MyPanelB::FuncB(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is Func B");
}

The problem occurs in the functions MyPanelA::MyPanelA(wxNotebook* parent) and MyPanelB::MyPanelB(wxNotebook* parent). Lets focus on the first. If I use the binding line Button1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelA::FuncA, this, wxID_ANY) as is currently in the code above, everything works just fine. But if I use instead the following commented line Button1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyPanelB::FuncB, this, wxID_ANY) which referes to the function in PanelB, I get an compiler error 'cannot convert argument 1 from 'EventHandler* const' to 'T *'.
I'm not sure what this error means, but I've got a feeling I'm not sending the correct object, and that I should be using something other than 'this'. Is this true? If so, what object should I be using and how can I find it?

"I've got a feeling I'm not sending the correct object..." Provide a [mcve]. Something that can be copy/pasted and used to reproduce the said issue/error.

(updated answer after the source code has been provided)
You're trying to pass this, which is MyPanelB*, as the pointer to call MyPanelA::FuncA() on. This obviously (and luckily) doesn't compile as calling a member function of a class on an object of a different class could never work.
I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but it goes without saying that you need to pass the object pointer matching the class of the member function you want to bind.

this is a const pointer in a const member function, but if your function is non-const, then the only other explanation I see is that your class doesn't derive from wxEvtHandler — I should have probably mentioned this in the answer, but this seemed like something too obvious to overlook. But maybe not?

My functions are not const, at least not as far as I can tell. What do you mean by classes that are derived from wxEvtHandler?
When I bind FuncA from within PanelA or FuncB from within PanelB - the binding works just fine. The error occurs only when I try running the functions from classes that they are not members of. I'll try to prepare a simplified example and edit it in to the question soon.

I added a sample code, as suggested, which demonstrates the problem.
It would be great if anyone understands the reason for error and can explain it to me and how to fix it. Thanks!

I meant C const* by const pointer, of course. But no matter, the problem is not this, I've updated the answer.

@VZ. Yeah, but note that beginner can get confused by calling C const* a const pointer. So we should stick with correct terms. C const* is a pointer to a const C. Anyways I'll delete my previuos comments as you've removed that term now.

@VZ, how can I pass the object pointer of the second class to a function of the first class? I can't figure out a way to achieve this.
What I'm trying to do is to share information between panels. My thought was that I if I could bind a function from the one panel in a function of another panel, this could be achieved. Or alternatively, by binding a custom event. Is there a better way to do this?

You need to store the pointer to the panel somewhere and then use it when calling Bind(). There is no magic here, if you want an object to receive the event, you need to somehow specify this object.
